# jQuery atWho in HTML to produce @mention style text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to utilise @mention capability when inputting text into a form field. I have found the exact code to do it from this site [jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ourcodeworld/83vLzhw2/3/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=83vLzhw2) and it's awseom when you do it in there.

However, when I try to create an HTML page that incorporates the HTML and JavaScript together, it doesn't work, see below. Firstly, I had to go and find the complete link for jquery-3.2.1 because it couldn't be found and errored in console. Now it doesn't error but also doesn't work.

Where it says "**any my favourite city is**" you can type an @ and then options London, Stuttgart and Köln should display which is triggered by the script.

```
<html>
<head>
   <div id="inputcity" contenteditable="true">and my favourite city is </div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">

// Initialize city field within content editable

  $('#inputcity').atwho({
     at: "@",
     data:['London', 'Stuttgart', 'Köln']
  });
</script>

</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's your `atwho` function?

Comment: @j08691 I got it from here https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/516/how-to-create-a-mentions-autocomplete-with-jquery-and-atwho

Comment: where would I add this? `<link href="css/jquery.atwho.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I think I jumped ahead - I had missed an important first step. I'll check it out - thought I had everything self-contained as it worked in jfiddle

Comment: Are you adding it to your page (not the fiddle)? If so why don't we see it in the code above? Your question should include a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this scripts to your code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ichord/At.js/master/dist/css/jquery.atwho.css" />

<!-- jquery.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ichord/Caret.js/master/dist/jquery.caret.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ichord/At.js/master/dist/js/jquery.atwho.min.js"></script>
```

Here's working example.

```html
<div id="inputcity" contenteditable="true">and my favourite city is </div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ichord/At.js/master/dist/css/jquery.atwho.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ichord/Caret.js/master/dist/jquery.caret.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ichord/At.js/master/dist/js/jquery.atwho.min.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize city field within content editable
  $('#inputcity').atwho({
    at: "@",
    data: ['London', 'Stuttgart', 'Köln']
  });
</script>
```

Because of the package you're using (At.js) is not maintained anymore you could use [tribute](https://github.com/zurb/tribute) package.

Comment: thank you for this, I had missed those vital scripts, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contained a couple of syntax errors (unclosed tags, mostly). I cleaned it up and cobbled this together:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="inputcity" contenteditable="true">and my favourite city is </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ichord/At.js@master/dist/css/jquery.atwho.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ichord/At.js@master/dist/js/jquery.atwho.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize city field within content editable
    $('#inputcity').atwho({
      at: "@",
      data: ['London', 'Stuttgart', 'Köln']
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Two caveats, though: [At.js is unmaintained](https://github.com/ichord/At.js#%EF%B8%8F-announcement-%EF%B8%8F), and relying on the version on the `master` branch is something I did for convenience. In production, you'd use something that is supported (the author recommends [ZURB Tribute](https://github.com/zurb/tribute)), and use a proper package manager.